# mediastreamtrack.getsources not supported in firefox, how to do the equivalent

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

is there an equivalent way to get the list of video devices connected to the PC? I have an external webcam connection in addition to the build-in one.

mediastreamtrack.getsources is working in chrome but firefox reported "TypeError: MediaStreamTrack.getSources is not a function".  I am running firefox version 25.0.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) is now supported by Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: It's now supported as `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`: see examples https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ and https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/multi/.

Comment: What about `MediaStreamTrack.getSources`? Is it deprecated?

Comment: Is mediastreamtrack deprecated?

Comment: `MediaStreamTrack.getSources` is deprecated: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4765305641369600. `MediaStreamTrack` is not deprecated.

Comment: Is the `mediastreamtrack.getsources` deprecated?

Comment: @M98 as per my reply, MediaStreamTrack.getSources is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below-mentioned code. It is working properly giving all audio and video devices list.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        .then(function (devices) {
            devices.forEach(function (device) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = device.deviceId;
                if (device.kind === 'videoinput') {
                    option.text = device.label || 'camera' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
                    videoSelect.appendChild(option);
                } else if (device.kind == 'audioinput') {
                    option.text = device.label || 'mic' + (audioSelect.length + 1);
                    audioSelect.appendChild(option);
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
        });
```

Comment: What are audioSelect and videoSelect in your example?

Comment: code is not working please write full code what is videoSelect ?? and audioSelect ???

Answer (score 1):

As of Nightly 28.0a1 Firefox does not have anything equivalent to Chrome's MediaStreamTrack.getSources. So, no, there is not currently a way to get a list of the local audio and video devices in Firefox.

I asked the developers working on Firefox's WebRTC implementation and they say this is a planned feature but no ETA on when it will land. You can view the [irc log](http://logbot.glob.com.au/?c=mozilla%23media&s=21+Nov+2013&e=21+Nov+2013) (scroll to 16:17) if you're curious.

Also, here's the relevant part in the [draft W3C spec](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#enumerating-devices).

Comment: Do you think a list would be obtainable using `MediaStream.getVideoTracks()` [MediaStream API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack)?

Answer (score -3):

As of Firefox 34, `MediaStreamTrack` is now available.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack

Comment: As far as I can tell, that documentation does not mention the `getSources()` method, and currently shipping versions of Firefox 34 and 35 do not implement it.